# Merge chat-history into chat, cloud-storage into cloud

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Another candidate for merging: [chat-history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat-history) is used by only 2 questions (both times together with [google-talk](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk)). Then there's [chat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat), used 7 times.

Suggestion: Merge [chat-history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat-history) into [chat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat) and either make the former a synonym to the later, or simply drop it. Though in the latter case it might pop-up again if we just wait for the emptied tag to be auto-purged ;)

Same goes for [cloud-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) (x1), which should be merged into [cloud](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud) (x14 currently).

Comment: I agree, makes sense

Comment: Seems already done for `cloud-storage` -> `cloud` meanwhile.

Comment: If you both like the idea, then why does nobody upvote my answer? :)

Comment: I do not only like the idea, I even made the proposal. And right you are -- here goes my +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds good. I like the proposal.

Comment: So now that you are mod: Proceed? :) 'chat-history' is still a stand-alone (x2) to be merged into `chat` (x8). `cloud-storage` already was merged and synonymized.